# can't create private elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create a private elastic beanstalk environment inside my VPC. By "private" I mean that it should be an elastic service available only inside my VPC and not from the internet.

I used the elastic beanstalk new app wizard, selected python 3.4 as the environment, added an RDS DB, changed the instance type to t2.xlarge. I deployed the app and everything was OK.

Later I went to the vpc page, and changed the settings to not allocate a public ip and the load visibility to "internal".

When I deploy my changes it is in a waiting state for about 30 minutes.
I get a few of these messages while waiting for the update:

> Still waiting for the following 1 instances to become healthy

later I get this message:

> Environment health has transitioned from Info to Degraded.
>   Configuration update in progress on 1 instance. 0 out of 2 instances
>   completed (running for 12 minutes). No data received from 1 out of 2
>   instances. ELB health is failing or not available for 1 out of 2
>   instances.

and eventually I get this message:

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named
>   aborted operation. Current state:
>   'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: The following resource(s) failed
>   to update: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].

I also tried deploying the service as private from the beginning and got similar results. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: The "ELB health is failing" message leads me to believe that the health check on the Load Balancer is failing to connect. Is your ELB in the same VPC as your EB instances?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same VPC. Should I open anything in the security group?

Comment: The security group on the EB instances needs to allow inbound traffic from the ELB for the health check to work. How is your health check configured?